# Automatically update and test npm dependencies

Tags: angularjs, dependency-management, npm

I would like to automate the following sequence of events;

- A new version of Angular is released on Github
- 'Something' triggers causing all our angular applications to update their npm dependencies for angular to the latest
- The applications build, run unit tests and push to UAT on success, notify success/failure condition.

The way I am currently thinking of configuring this process is to configure our CI server to monitor the Github tags for Angular, and trigger on a new tag with a specific structure. Then this would trigger something like npm-check-updates, or just a straightforward npm update angular, and then our regular UAT build process in the CI server continues.

This got me thinking about the grand scheme of managing a swath of dependencies across many projects. I would like a way to be automatically notified of stable builds in various npm dependencies, and have that dependency automatically update and build on UAT for all my apps that have said dependency. I tried googling around for this solution but can't really find anything, which begs the question, how do you appropriately manage dependency lifecycle? Is this currently a manual process for most organisations?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps a bit late, but for open source github repos there's https://greenkeeper.io/ it does exactly what you want, it opens a new PR for you every time a package has an update, which will automatically run whichever CI you have in place and test the updated version. It's up to you to merge or decline

Comment: This looks pretty much what I was after. Though I will add that I just did what I said I would do in the question, it works, but I feel it lacks a lot of transparency. I've added slack notifications to the process which gives some form of oversight into the automation, but a system like GreenKeeper would be better. It's a damn shame Greenkeeper don't provide immediate access to a free trial account, I imagine they are losing a lot of business via the ~paywall

Comment: Yeah it's probably not a very good model to pay for something just to see how it works, the only way to test it is using an open source dummy repo to understand the functionality, still if you ever develop an open source npm based library, this is one of the best tools to lower the effort to keep your package up to date